# Counting values before a date, iterating for every row

Tags: python, pandas

So i have this dataframe:

```
+----------------+--------------+------------+
| TransactionID  |   TimeKey    | ProductKey |
+----------------+--------------+------------+
|        3621015 | '2018-01-01' |       6151 |
|        3621015 | '2018-01-01' |       4354 |
|        3487373 | '2018-01-02' |       6151 |
|        4378337 | '2018-01-03' |       6151 |
|        4378337 | '2018-01-03' |       4354 |
|        4378337 | '2018-01-03' |       3783 |
+----------------+--------------+------------+
```

It is a database about transactions and their respective date, and the product that was bought.

I want to count, for every row, the number of times that a certain product has appeared before.
Something like this:

```
+----------------+--------------+------------+-------+
| TransactionID  |   TimeKey    | ProductKey | count |
+----------------+--------------+------------+-------+
|        3621015 | '2018-01-01' |       6151 | NaN/0 |
|        3621015 | '2018-01-01' |       4354 | NaN/0 |
|        3487373 | '2018-01-02' |       6151 | 1     |
|        4378337 | '2018-01-03' |       6151 | 2     |
|        4378337 | '2018-01-03' |       4354 | 1     |
|        4378337 | '2018-01-03' |       3783 | NaN/0 |
+----------------+--------------+------------+-------+
```

Right now i *could* do it, but the way i do it is awful.
My solution:

```
for index, row in data.iterrows():
    data['count'] = data[(data['ProductKey'] == row['ProductKey']) & (data['TimeKey'] <= row['TimeKey'])]['ProductKey'].count()
```

Doing this for 30 lines is okay, but i'm working with a couple houndred thousand lines :\ Looking for ideas

Comment: Have you read the Pandas docs?

Comment: Not all of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume your `TimeKey` is already in ***increasing order*** as in the sample, you need `groupby` and `cumcount` as follows

```
data['count'] =  data.groupby('ProductKey').cumcount()

Out[384]:
   TransactionID       TimeKey  ProductKey  count
0        3621015  '2018-01-01'        6151      0
1        3621015  '2018-01-01'        4354      0
2        3487373  '2018-01-02'        6151      1
3        4378337  '2018-01-03'        6151      2
4        4378337  '2018-01-03'        4354      1
5        4378337  '2018-01-03'        3783      0
```

---

*Note*: If `TimeKey` is not in increasing order, you need to sort dataframe by it before running command above. If you sort it, you need it in proper datetime format for the correct sorting

Answer (score 0):

`data['Count'] = data.groupby(['ProductKey'])['ProductKey'].count()`.

This provides the count of each ProductKey. If you do not want counts to be NaN, then run the following snippet.

`data.fillna(value = 0, inplace = True)`

Comment: i want the count value to be the number of times that the product appeared **before** that time key.